# Change visibility being lost in RTC source control

Tags: rtc

When i create a new stream in RTC source control I take a snapshot of the current stream and create a new stream from this snapshot.

If I right click on a file in RTC source control and click "View History" then just the changes made in the current stream are displayed. If changes were made a previous stream(s1) and this new stream(s2) is created based on that stream(s1) then I do not see the changes made to the file in s1 . I can search for change sets on the stream and try to find the file that changed but this is a difficult process.

How can the entire history of file changes be viewed on RTC source control regardless of what stream the changes were made ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the repository files of a component (directly in the component section of your project area).

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/2.0/process-getting-started/images/team_artifacts_view.png]

See the component folder in the picture above: a show history from a component in that folder, as opposed to a component in a stream, would display the full history of that file, instead of the filtered one from a stream.

---

This is similar to the "Show all in history" [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148353/6309) by [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387301/scott-cowan).
See "[RTC file/element revision history](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/77144/rtc-fileelement-revision-history)":

> In the Eclipse client, you can right click over a file loaded into a workspace and select "`Team -> Show History`".
>   **This shows you the history of that file in that workspace**.

[image: Show all]

> You can then click on the "`Show all in repository`" tool icon, to see the history of all versions of that file. (You can do the same thing to a file in a stream/workspace repository files view, with the "Show History" operation).

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of that section? That section does not seem viewable for top level "Project Area"

Comment: @Adrian screenshot added

Comment: thank you. It seems now I can view the history of a file for previous streams even if I right click "view history" on the file itself. This contradicts my original question. Is there something in RTC that turns this on/off , in other words if I right click on a file and then view history should I always see the history of that file across streams ?

Comment: @blue-sky no, maybe you are asking the history on a file obtained through a "show repository files" done on a component within the global components section, instead of the component shown in your stream. That, or the "Show all in history" button remains activated once pressed, and you would need to "un-click" it in order to restore the filter.

Answer (score 0):

In the History View there is a button in the toolbar to "Show All in History".

Scott